# Can we use a magnetic vector potential in the case of time varying $E$-fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, gauge-theory, maxwell-equations, gauge-invariance

Most discussions of the magnetic vector potential defined through $\mathbf{B}=\nabla\times\mathbf{A}$ are only for working with static electric fields (for example, Griffiths:

[image]

If we instead require that

$$\nabla\times\mathbf{B}=\nabla\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{A}) = \nabla(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A})\ -\nabla^2\mathbf{A} = \mu_0\mathbf{J} +\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$$

using the full form of Ampere's law, then we can still have the freedom to choose an $\mathbf{A}$ with zero divergence, giving us a form of Poisson's equation:

$$\nabla^2\mathbf{A} = -\mu_0\mathbf{J} -\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$$

Which can be solved in principle using analogies to the electric scalar potential $V$.

Why is this form of the magnetic vector potential in its full generality seldom seen? Is there a contradiction which prevents its use?

Comment: Turn ahead to Section 10.1 in your copy of Griffiths, and look for the phrase "Coulomb gauge".

Comment: BTW your curl of the curl you wrote down is in correct

Comment: "Why is this form of the magnetic vector potential in its full generality seldom seen?" Why should choosing a specific gauge ($\nabla\cdot A=0$) be considered "full generality"?

Comment: to add on to Oliver. All gauges are all equally correct and all predict the same E and B fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be used,

Given,$ \nabla × A = B$

Then

$\nabla ×E = -\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}$

$\nabla × E = -\frac{\partial (\nabla × A)  }{\partial t}$

$\nabla × E = -\nabla × \frac{\partial  A }{\partial t}$

$\nabla × E  + \nabla × \frac{\partial  A }{\partial t} = 0$

$\nabla × (E  +  \frac{\partial  A }{\partial t})= 0$

Because the curl of this quantity is zero, it can be written as the gradient of a scalar function ( or the negative of a gradient of a scalar function, which is used to match the definition of electrostatic potential)

$E  +  \frac{\partial  A }{\partial t} = -\nabla V$

$E = -\nabla V  -\frac{\partial  A }{\partial t} $

From here we can substitute the definitions of E into the other maxwell equations

This will obtain 2 equations that interlink A and V in terms of the source terms $\rho$ and J.

using the "lorenz" gauge choice ( not lorentz) we can decouple these and solve easier( or using the coulomb gauge)

This is called the potential formulation of maxwells equations

Comment: Also, when learning the potential formulation it is important you actually understand WHY we can prescribe the divergence of A to follow specific gauges. Look at my answer here ; https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/682626/lorenz-gauge-for-non-homogenous-wave-equations-in-vacuum/682654?noredirect=1#comment1530697_682654