# Coulomb gauge with $\rho = 0$ implies Lorenz gauge?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-theory, maxwell-equations, gauge

Maxwell equations take the form:

$$\nabla^2 \phi + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \nabla \cdot \vec{A}= - \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}\qquad (\nabla^2 \vec{A} - \mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial^2 \vec{A}}{\partial t^2}) - \nabla (\nabla \cdot \vec{A} + \mu_0\epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t})=-\mu_0 \vec{J}$$

In the Coulomb gauge, when $\rho = 0$, Maxwell equations take the form:

$$\nabla^2 \phi = 0 \qquad\nabla^2 \vec{A} - \mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial^2 \vec{A}}{\partial t^2} =-\mu_0 \vec{J} $$

When $\rho = 0$, in the Coulomb gauge, $\phi = c$, meaning $\mu_0\epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = 0$. This means we can also identify that

$$\nabla \cdot \vec{A} + \mu_0\epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = 0$$

So in the case when $\rho = 0$ we have

$$\nabla \cdot \vec{A} = 0 \qquad \nabla \cdot \vec{A} + \mu_0\epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = 0$$

i.e., the potentials $\phi$ and $\vec{A}$ in the Coulomb gauge  also satisfy the Lorenz gauge.

But when we solve Maxwell equations in the Lorenz gauge under $\rho = 0$ we obtain the equations

$$\nabla^2 \phi =\mu_0 \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2}  \qquad \nabla^2 \vec{A} - \mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial^2 \vec{A}}{\partial t^2} =-\mu_0 \vec{J}$$

These equations are different, namely $\phi$ has different solutions.

Am I correct in my logic if I say the potentials from the Coulomb gauge when $\rho = 0$ satisfy the Lorenz gauge? But the converse is NOT true, that the potentials from the Lorenz gauge when $\rho = 0$ do not need to satisfy the Coulomb gauge.

**EDIT - Another problem**

In fact because $A$ is the same for both gauges, and in the Coulomb gauge $-\nabla \phi = 0$, in order to leave the field invariant, $-\nabla \phi$ in the Lorenz gauge must be 0 as well. So it doesn't really matter that $\phi$ doesn't satisfy the coulomb gauge in the Lorenz gauge, as it disappear anyway when finding the fields! $\vec{A}$ is the only thing that matters, and is the same for both!

But, if my understanding of the scalar homogeneous wave equation is correct, a solution of it is $\phi = \cos(kx-\omega t)$, whose gradient is not zero? If it wasn't zero, the field would be gauge dependant (as in the Coulomb gauge it is zero)? Help!

Comment: "EDIT - Another problem..." Please, no. If you have a new question, you should ask a new question, not edit your previous question. You are forcing answerers to try and hit a moving target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lorenz gauge is an example of an *incomplete gauge*. This means that the defining condition $\nabla \cdot \vec A + \epsilon_0\mu_0 \partial \phi/\partial t =0$ is not enough to uniquely specify a gauge. Sometimes we say that there is *residual gauge freedom*.  Explicitly, a generic gauge transformation takes the form
$$\matrix{\phi \mapsto \phi - \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\chi\\\vec A \mapsto \vec A + \nabla \chi}$$
for some scalar function $\chi(\vec r,t)$.  Inserting this into the Lorenz gauge condition we obtain

$$\left(\nabla^2- \epsilon_0\mu_0 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right)\chi = 0$$

In other words, given any choice of potentials $(\vec A,\phi)$ which satisfy the Lorenz gauge condition and vanish at spatial infinity, we may choose any arbitrary compactly-supported solution $\chi$ to the homogeneous wave equation and perform a gauge transformation to yield another gauge which also obeys the Lorenz condition and the same spatial boundary conditions. The Lorenz condition therefore doesn't define a single gauge, but rather a *family* of gauges which require additional gauge fixing conditions to specify uniquely.

The same is **not** true of the Coulomb gauge (at least on the domain $\mathbb R^3$). Performing a gauge transformation on the Coulomb condition $\nabla \cdot \vec A = 0$ yields $\nabla^2 \chi=0$; imposing the spatial boundary condition that $\chi\rightarrow 0 $ as $r\rightarrow 0$ yields that $\chi=0$ everywhere.

If $\rho=0$ everywhere, then Gauss' law says that $\nabla \cdot E = -\nabla^2 \phi = 0 \implies \phi = 0$, when subject to the same Dirichlet boundary conditions at infinity.  Furthermore, in the Coulomb gauge we have that $\nabla \cdot \vec A=0$. As a result, we would have that the Lorenz condition $\nabla \cdot A + \epsilon_0 \mu_0 \partial \phi/\partial t=0$ would be satisfied automatically. In this case the Coulomb gauge would be one of an infinity of possible gauges which obey the Lorenz gauge condition, with the others being obtained by choosing a solution $\chi$ to the homogeneous wave equation and performing the corresponding gauge transformation.

> Am I correct in my logic in saying the potentials from the coulomb gauge when ρ=0 satisfy the lorenz gauge. But the converse is NOT true, that the potentials from the lorenz gauge when ρ=0 do not need to satisfy the coulomb gauge.

Yes.

> in fact because A is the same for both gauges[...]

$\vec A$ need not be the same for both gauges.  If we choose the Coulomb gauge with Dirichlet boundary conditions at infinity, there is only one $\vec A= \vec A_C$ available to us, while $\phi$ must vanish.  If we choose the Lorenz gauge condition, then the aformentioned potentials are a possible choice, but we may also have $\phi=-\partial \chi/\partial t$ and $\vec A = \vec A_C + \nabla \chi$ for any compactly-supported solution $\chi$ to the homogeneous wave equation.

Comment: For your equation for "x", inserting the definitions of the gauge transformations into  the lorenz gauge produce something different from what I have calculated before. Your "0" term, is instead replaced with a copy of the - lorenz gauge condition of the untransformed potentials  . Why have you made them 0? As these are different than the potentials we transformed, and thus cannot resuscitate into it to make it zero?   And yes you are correct, $\vec{A}$ need not be the same, I should have said satisfy the same equation! --

Comment: But what about the apparent contradiction? Although $\vec{A}$ may not be the same, we could in theory choose them to be the same. In that case. In order for the field to be invariant, -\nabla \phi must be the same for both gauges. In the coulomb gauge -\nabla \phi = 0, and thus in the lorenz gauge it must also be zero. But assuming I haven't got confused with the homogenous wave equation, Taking the gradient of one of its  solutions doesn't have to be zero! (I would suspect If we manually impose the condition that it must vanish at infnity, then the potential might be the same in both gauges -

Comment: @jensenpaull I am confused - the Lorenz gauge condition is that $\nabla \cdot \vec A + \epsilon_0 \mu_0 \partial \phi/\partial t \color{red}{=0}$.  If you replace $\vec A$ with $\vec A + \nabla \chi$ and $\phi$ with $\phi - \partial \chi/\partial t$, then the Lorenz gauge condition becomes $(\nabla^2-\epsilon_0 \mu_0 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2})\chi \color{red}{=0}$.

Comment: But if we relax this condition(which still should be valid) then the equation for $\phi $ doesn't need to have a solution where the gradient is zero?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/682626/lorenz-gauge-for-non-homogenous-wave-equations-in-vacuum/682654#682654 here Is what I mean. The right hand side cannot be replaced with zero, as it is the UN transformed potentials, which isn't the lorenz gauge, so cannot be replaced with zero? Replacing the right with zero, would invalidate the entire proof, as that would mean  I DIDNT need to transform them, to satisfy the lorenz gauge

Comment: @jensenpaull If you re-read my answer, I said that **if** $(\phi,\vec A)$ obey the Lorenz condition, **then** $(\phi-\partial \chi/\partial t, \vec A + \nabla \chi)$ will *also* obey the Lorenz condition as long as $\chi$ obeys the homogeneous wave equation. In your linked answer, you are showing that given **any** gauge, it's possible to perform a gauge transformation so that the new potentials obey the Lorenz condition. In **my** answer, I am showing that given a gauge which **already** obeys the Lorenz condition, we can find a different gauge which **also** obeys the Lorenz condition.

Comment: Ah yes, thank your for clearing that up, it's a specific solution to your "x" under the assumption we are already in the lorenz gauge. but how does this relate to my confusion between  $- \nabla \phi$ having to be the same for both the coulomb gauge, and the lorenz gauge, IF I choose $\vec{A}$ to be the same for both ( which can always be done) , I'm pretty sure I can find solutions of $\phi $ that satisfy the homogenous wave equation, whose gradient is NOT zero?( which contradicts the coulomb gauge)

Comment: I assume my confusion is solving the homogenous equation wrong. Can you show that $-\nabla \phi = 0$ always, in the lorenz gauge, when $\rho = 0$

Comment: @jensenpaull Let me get this straight. You're saying that the potentials $(\phi,\vec A)=(0, \vec A_C)$ are the potentials you get in the Coulomb gauge.  Now you want to perform a gauge transformation in which $\vec A$ is left unchanged?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135664/discussion-between-j-murray-and-jensen-paull).

Comment: Instead of performing another gauge transformation, I am just getting confused with the need to keep the field invariant, $$\vec{E} = -\nabla \phi - \frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}$$ When $\rho = 0$ in both the coulomb gauge, and the lorenz gauge, $\vec{A}$ obeys the inhomogenous wave equation. Meaning in either gauge let's set $\vec{A}$ to be the same for both, call it $ \vec{A}_{1}$ in order to leave the field invariant, if $\vec{A } $is the same for either gauge, the value of $-\nabla \phi$ must be the same, in either gauge, otherwise the field is not invariant. --

Comment: In the coulomb gauge, \phi = c meaning -\nabla \phin= 0, meaning in order for the field to be invariant, $-\nabla \phi$ must be zero in the lorenz gauge. Yet in the lorenz gauge $\phi$ satisfies the homogenous wave equation, which I am pretty sure I can show has solution where $\nabla \phi ≠ 0$

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same issue I had on my OP edit.

In both gauges $\vec{A} $ must satisfy:

$ \nabla^2 \vec{A} - \mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial^2 \vec{A}}{\partial t^2} =-\mu_0 \vec{J}$

And the corresponding gauge condition independantly aswell.

To make $\vec{A}$ the same for both gauge choices.

We know $\vec{A}$ has to independantly satisfy both gauge choices

$\nabla \cdot \vec{A} = 0$

$\nabla \cdot \vec{A} =-\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}$

It follows that:

$-\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = 0$

**Lorenz Gauge:**

$\nabla^2 \phi =\epsilon_0\mu_0 \frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial t^2}$

$ \nabla^2 \vec{A} - \mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial^2 \vec{A}}{\partial t^2} =-\mu_0 \vec{J}$

Substituting, $-\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = 0$

We get:

$\nabla^2 \phi = 0$

$ \nabla^2 \vec{A} - \mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial^2 \vec{A}}{\partial t^2} =-\mu_0 \vec{J}$

Which is the coulomb gauge:

Meaning for the case where $\vec{A}$ is the same for both gauges, it follows that in either gauge,

$\phi = c$

$-\nabla (c) = 0$

And thus there is no contradiction, as solutions to the homogenous wave equation whose gradient is non zero, are not permitted in the restrictions on $\nabla \cdot \vec{A}$